# Easygui Directory Open Box Issue

Tags: python, easygui

I have recently been working on a simple project for duplicating files, and I have made decent progress. However, while I was adding the feature to select the duplicated file's location, I ran into an issue.

I am using easygui as the file and directory selector, and I use the function `easygui.diropenbox()`. However, every time the directory box is opened with the code, it always appears on the bottom left corner, and is never draggable. Not even the entire box is visible on screen.

```
import easygui
file = easygui.diropenbox()
print(file)
```

Comment: It works for me. What version of python are you using and what operating system?

Comment: I am using Python 3.8 on OS X 10.10 "Yosemite"

Comment: Well, I don't have OS X, but you could try upgrading to the latest python if that's possible for you. Also search for `"easygui on os x yosemite"` and a number of stack overflow links come up.